# Magento 2.3 admin is redirecting to this URl domain/admin/admin/denid/key/**** after admin login

Tags: admin, magento2.3, url, acl

I anonymously added some ACL permissions in Magento 2 and saved.
I know that I have configured wrongly in the process of knowing, how it works since then I am unable to access my Magento 2 admin, I am able to login but later the URL is redirecting to

> **domain/admin/admin/denid/key/**

result **This page isn’t working** working error.

clearing cache but didn't work. Suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it your primary admin account you created during setup ?

Comment: Have you made any changes to your .htaccess/ngnix config file recently or modified your admin URL

Comment: @AbdulPathan, Actually I have created another user and tried with them . but there isn't any change in the result

Comment: @DavaGordon  No I haven't made any changes to those files

Comment: @RajuPotharaju could you please send screenshot of your database table `authorization_role` & `authorization_rule` ??

Comment: @AbdulPathan                                         Authorization_ role: https://www.screencast.com/t/DQVTBK9A7DPd                    Authorization_Rule https://www.screencast.com/t/MHiSxi24X